# Fastest of most efficient way to find a parent element

Tags: jquery, find, parent-child

I have been using this method for a while now having initially not put any research into it.

```
$("div#panel-frame div.panel.txt select.fontsize").live('change', function ()
            {
                var parent = $(this).parents('div.panel.txt');
});
```

So as you can see from the code above, I'm trying to get access to a parent of select.fontsize. The parent I'm trying to get to is div.panel.txt - as you can see, I'm accessing it by saying $(this).parents('div.panel.txt')

This method works but I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing it? Ideally I want it to be as fast and efficient as possible.

Comment: Offtopic: `.live` is a bit of a dinosaur really. Use `$(document).delegate("div#panel-frame div.panel.txt select.fontsize", "change", eventHandlerFunction);` instead.

Comment: hmm o.k - i've not seen that. FYI I am populating this select on the fly using Ajax - which is kind of why i'm using live instead of binding it normally. I have been constrained by time so never really put effort into research. It just worked. Now I have the time to start making my code more efficient. I'll check out delegate, thanks!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=delegate+live+jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have inside your change function should be efficient enough, though if you know that the element you want is the *direct parent*, you should use .parent() instead of .parents(). As other people have said, if you don't know whether it's the direct parent, use .closest() instead of .parents().

In theory, you can use `this.parentNode` to get the parent - regardless of its node or class names - with native DOM traversal (that is, without using jQuery), and that might be a bit quicker. However, you would need to write your own checks to make sure the node and class names match, so any gains you make would probably be lost again. This is basically what jQuery is doing under the hood anyway, and jQuery is very heavily optimised already.

Your `.live` selector `$("div#panel-frame div.panel.txt select.fontsize")` is probably a bigger worry in terms of speed. `.live()` works by assigning an event to the body element, and then watching the targets of events as they bubble up. So, when any 'change' event hits the body, jQuery needs to check if it originated at something matching `'div#panel-frame div.panel.txt select.fontsize'`, which is a very slow operation, especially in older browsers.

It would probably be quicker to just bind `.live()` to $('select.fontsize'), and then check if the select element is the kind you want within the event handler itself. That way, jQuery can use the browser's native 'getElementsByTagName', which is a fast operation. Better yet, give your `select.fontsize` elements a more specific class name, so you know in advance that they're the ones you want.

Comment: Good point about the relative (in)efficiencies of `.live` vs. ancestor-traversal within the event handler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Beejamin. The reason i'm using Live() is because the select is being populated on the fly in this case using Ajax. I'm not sure if in this instance I can bind live()?

Comment: You can bind .live() to any selector - because it's really bound to the body element. Basically, jQuery watches at the level of the body, and checks to see if any events it sees (in your case, 'change' events) match the selector you use. That's why you should use a fast selector - to speed up that check.

Comment: If you're only populating the `option` elements of the select, rather than creating the `select` itself on the fly, I'm fairly sure you can just bind `change` to the select itself. The change event will have access to whatever options the select has at the moment the event is fired.

Comment: Just tried to bind it normally and it worked fine - not sure what I was doing there using live! There are lots of events where I definitely needed to use live (although I will go back and check them), I think I got carried away whilst writing it. I'm definitely learning now though, thanks for your help with this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a true *parent* (i.e. next ancestor) element you're after, this should be sufficient:

```
var parent = $(this.parentNode); // is faster than $(this).parent();
```

If you only want the parent if it matches the selector, then is will do the trick:

```
var parent = $(this).parent('div.panel.txt');
if ( parent[0] ) {
   ...
```

However, if you're after an *ancestor* element, then you probably want to use the `.closest()` method:

```
var parent = $(this).closest('div.panel.txt');
```

which walks up the dom tree and stops at the first ancestor that matches the selector.

Comment: Excellent, in most cases I am using this to get the direct parent so .parent() will do the trick for me. Thank you for the other pieces of advice, they will come in handy later on.

Comment: :-) BTW, `.parents()` is the *least* efficient method for this, as it always walks up the whole dom tree and returns all the elements that match the selector.

Answer (score 3):

Fastest, or "most correct?" Use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of `parents` if you only want the first such ancestor.

Comment: Well in this case it is the closest so that might work better.

Comment: .closest() is faster than .parents() because it stops as soon as it hits a match (whereas .parents() keeps checking even after a match). .parent() is even faster, because it only considers the direct parent node. That might work for you.

Comment: I hesitate to recommend `.parent()` because it can silently break if some well-meaning developer adds a `<div>` when you don't expect it. Hence my concern to start with the most correct solution, then optimize only when necessary. @Beejamin, your comment about `.live()` is a good example about why.

Comment: On further investigation, I had to go back and use closest. This is because the select was nested within a table so it's parent was actually a td.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re only looking for *one* ancestor, you can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find it. `.parents()` will find *all of* the ancestors which match the selector.